# jQuery: Set cookie on one page and retrieve from another

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have two HTML pages.

`setcookie.html`:

```
<script>    
if($.cookie('order_by') == null){
   $.cookie('order_by', 'Name');
}
console.log($.cookie('order_by'))  //Works fine
</script>
```

Now, I want to retrieve this cookie on some other page which I am not able to do. Now, there is a link in `setcookie.html` which takes me to `getcookie.html`.

`getcookie.html`:

```
<script>    
console.log($.cookie('order_by'))  //Doesn't work
</script>
```

As the cookie is already set(and it's never expiring), I should be able to retrieve its value on some other page. Right?

How can I do so?

**EDIT:**

This is the whole HTML of `getcookie.html`.

```
<ul class="filter-by">
<li>
Filter by<br /><script>$('.filter-by li').append('<strong>'+$.cookie('order_by' , { path: '/' })+'</strong>');</script>
 <ul class="filter-items-list">
   <li>Name</li>
   <li>Views</li>
   <li>Latest</li>
   <li>Downloads</li>
  </ul>
<script>
$('.filter-items-list li').click(function(e) {
$.cookie('order_by',$(this).html(),  { path: '/' });
location.reload();
});
</script>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9126459/2454376

Comment: @mishik I tried specifying path too but even that doesn't work.

Comment: Please show us the code with this too.

Comment: @mishik I will just edit the question.

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't it be `{ path: '/setcookie.html' }` ?

Comment: @mishik, No it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I see that is the problem. You need to *set* the cookie for the whole site:

setcookie.html:

```
$.cookie('order_by', 'Name', {'path': '/'});
```

getcookie.html:

```
console.log($.cookie('order_by'));
```