# Persist cookie form values across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

**The setting:** I have a form that captures`$thisSearch.val()`, saves it as a cookie, and pushes to an array. The form is an overlay triggered from a menu item in the header so this can appear on any page in the site.

**The issue** is that it only seems to save/persist the input values on/from that page it was entered on. I'm trying to collect all these values into one `list.items()` array that can be entered anywhere in the site.

**I've tried** pushing the string to the array myself instead of the `add` function and moved the dom around for the search form.

I can update question when I know what to specifically ask. Any pointers / concepts I should be aware of for this would be great.

```
var cookieList = function(cookieName) {
    var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName);
    var items = cookie ? cookie.split(/,/) : new Array();

    return {
        "add": function(val) {
            items.push(val);
            $.cookie(cookieName, items.join(','));
        },
        "items": function() {
            return items;
        }
    }
} 

var list = new cookieList("PreviousSearches");

$searchSubmit.on('click', function() {
    var $thisSearch = $(this).prev().find($searchInput);
    if( $thisSearch.val() == '' ) {
        alert('Please enter a search term');
        console.log( list );
        return false;            

    } else {
        searchTerm = $thisSearch.val() 
        list.add( searchTerm );
    }
});

var searchTerms = list.items();
var total = searchTermsFiltered;
var searchTermsFiltered = searchTerms.filter(Boolean).slice( - 5 ).reverse();
var searchtermClean = searchTermsFiltered.join();

$.each($(searchTermsFiltered), function(i,v){
    if (!window.location.origin)
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;
    var lastURLRaw = window.location.origin+'/bch/?s='+v;
    var lastURL = lastURLRaw.replace(/ /g, '+');
    listItem = '<li><a href="'+lastURL+'">'+v+'</a></li>';
    $('.tags, .search-tags').append(listItem );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the path specifier from jquerys $.cookie in this top answer below.

`$.cookie(cookieName, items.join(',')` **, { path: '/' });** from my code.

[why are my jquery cookies not available across multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126320/why-are-my-jquery-cookies-not-available-across-multiple-pages?rq=1)